# Interactive Brokers TWS API how to get Option Contract for given Expiration and Strike?

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

The TWS API has `reqContractDetails` function to get contract details but it's slow. Because, as TWS API doc says the resulting event stream with the results (list of option contracts) will be throttled.

And it suggests to use the `reqSecDefOptParams` function instead, that respond with list of `expirations` and `strikes` for the option chain.

**The question is** - how to further use those `expirations` and `strikes` to get the individual option contracts?

The `reqContractDetails` could be called to get the individual contract for every combination of `expiration` and `strike`. So instead of 1 call of `reqContractDetails` that respond with throttled list of N events - instead - N calls to `reqContractDetails` will be made to get 1 event.

But it seems like even in such individual calls - it's still throttled, after say 50 calls, next calls to `reqContractDetails` are throttled (I see in logs that first like 20-50 calls respond fast and then it just blocks and wait a lot).

Is there any better way to get the data? I need to get the **full option chain** with **all the contracts**.

**UPDATE:**

Half a year later - I made TWS API driver [ib_api](https://github.com/al6x/ib_api) - I found that's the best way to get prices from TWS API is - 1) first getting the individual option contracts 2) then fetching prices by contract ids 3) both in small batches 4) with retries, as there going to be random errors. The driver provides REST API and available in all languages, you may check the `get_stock_option_chain_prices` function in `ibm.nim` to see these steps in details - how to fetch the stock option prices.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @core I made TWS API driver [ib_api](https://github.com/al6x/ib_api), to get option prices you may refer to the `get_stock_option_chain_prices` function in `ibm.nim` - I found that's the best way to get prices from TWS API (first getting the individual contracts and then fetching prices by contract ids, both in small batches, with retry because there going to be random errors).